# start an application from notification bar in android

Tags: android

I have an application, I want to show my app icon to the notification bar when my application is running and i also want when user will click on my app icon present in the notification bar
my app will be open. How to do this? Please Help!

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is deprecated.  Here is the way to show a dialog, from google's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable
            .logo_listy).setContentTitle("My notification").setContentText("Hello World!");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Works Great. Might be helpful to someone to make it an "ongoing" notification: Notification noti = mBuilder.build();
        noti.flags =  Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

Comment: how do i set notification should be fire after every 2 minutes?

Answer (score 3):

Few suggestions:

- if you want icon in the notification bar, you must send some notification.
- Application cannot be started by clicking on the notification icon. It may be started by clicking to the notification, that will be available if user pull-down notification bar. For that purpose you need to create PendingIntent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post a notification with a pending intent which contains an intent to start your app.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html for how to do it in general and http://javablogs.com/Jump.action?id=628173 for a trap you may fall into.