# how to run my app in background 24X7 that listens for changes in contact database

Tags: android

i have written an app with service class and activity.

i started the service from activity like this

```
public class RecycleBinActivity extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    Uri cpath=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        cpath=ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(cpath, true, observer);

    }
    private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public MyContentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        Intent i=new Intent(RecycleBinActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),DeleteService.class);
        startService(i); 
    }
        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
        { 
             super.deliverSelfNotifications();
            return true;

        }

    }
    MyContentObserver observer=new MyContentObserver();

}
```

and my service implementation is shown below

```
public class DeleteService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    Notification nf;
    NotificationManager nfm;
    Uri cpath,lookupuri;
    String lookupkey;
    Cursor cur;
    Runnable refresher;
    ContentResolver cr;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

         cpath=ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;


                        // some action

                nfm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                  int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(DeleteService.this, 1, intent, 0);
             nf=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Contact Database changed",System.currentTimeMillis());
             nf.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Delete Event", "contact name", pi);
             nf.flags = nf.flags |
                     Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                     startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, nf);

            }






    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    public void onDestroy() {

    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Launch a background thread to do processing.
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
     public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            DeleteService getService() {
                return DeleteService.this;
            }

    }
}
```

when i run this app and modify the contacts it shows notification for the first time 
if i did modification again in a few seconds it doesn't work why please any one help me

Answer (score 2):

Because `onCreate` method is usually called once.

Actually, there is no guarantee that your app will work 24x7, because OS may kill it, if there lack of memory. Of course, if your service is "sticky" it will be recreated (so, it's almost 24x7).

Comment: A foreground service with capability to get started from boot is somewhat a 24X7 service.

Answer (score 2):

Move all your logic to **onStartCommand** which you want to occur every time a change is made. Because **onCreate** is called once the service is executed for the first time, afterwards **onStartCommand** is called every time (till the life of service) you execute **startService**.

To make it more flexible to run 24/7, make sure you do start your service after a phone is restarted by handling *Boot* broadcast.

*Permission:*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

*Broadcast:*

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your app 24x7 , put some icon in the notification bar from the onCreate() of your app . OS will take it as a priority process always if it is in the notification bar of the device and will not kill it . You can listen to boot complete for putting your app icon in Notification bar .

[start an application from notification bar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849690/start-an-application-from-notification-bar-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late: But this is the right answer as of now to listen to changes in the contact database:

> Use [Content Observer](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/) to listen to any change in the contact table.