# How to show my app icon as notification in status bar by using adobe air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I have created my own mp3 player to use on android by using adobe air. I need to show my app notification icon when it was minimized. And when i click notification icon, my app will active. I don't know how to write about that. If it would be easy for you, please give me big help. :-)

Comment: Have you done some research? What has turned up? And more importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: I don't believe Adobe provides anything in the language/run-time itself for doing this, but there are some native extensions out there if you search around: https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification

Comment: possible duplicate of [start an application from notification bar in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849690/start-an-application-from-notification-bar-in-android)